# Contest problem involving circles geometry

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles

> Consider a circle with center $O$. the chord $AB$ divide the circle
> into two areas $R_1$ and $R_2$ ( $AB$ is not diameter). suppose $S_1$
> be a circle which its center is inside $R_1$ and be tangent to $AB$
> and be tangent inside $S$. also suppose $S_2$ be a circle which its
> center is inside $R_2$ and be tangent to $AB$ and be tangent inside
> $S$. we know $S_2$ passes through $O$ and $X$ is contact point of $AB$
> and $S_1$. suppose $O$ and $X$ and center of $S_2$ lie on a straight
> line. if radius of $S_2$ be equal to $100$. what is the radius of
> $S_1$?
>
> $1)30\sqrt3\quad\quad2)20(1+\sqrt3)\quad\quad3)60\quad\quad4)72\quad\quad5)\text{none}$

I don't know how to approach this problem. as first step I should draw this but I'm not sure how to do it ( I can't draw a circle passes through $O$ and be tangent to $AB$ and also tangent inside the circle $S$ and have $O$ and $X$ and center of this circle on a straight line) . any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is a correct drawing of the problem.  I added a second figure showing another depiction of these geometric constraints.  It appears that $S_1$ is under-constrained.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I couldn't solve it yet but I think I should construct perpendicular lines from center of each circle to $AB$ and also somehow should prove $O$ is midpoint of center of $S_2$ and $X$. (also drawing perpendicular from $O$ to $AB$ should be useful)

Comment: It is not true that $O$ is the midpoint of line segment joining the center of $S_2$ and $X$, although this rendering of the problem does make it appear that way.  To help you see this, imagine how you could move around the components without violating any constraints.  Imagine that line $AB$ approaches $O$.  Then the line segment $XO$ shrinks while the radius of $S_2$ remains constant at a length of 100.

Comment: Actually...  By moving around line $AB$, the radius of $S_1$ changes.  Is the text in your question exactly what the problem says?  Because right now this geometry problem seems under-constrained, so I would answer 'none of the above'.

Comment: Yes, I translated what problem says in English. and to me it seems it is true that the radius can have different values.